# Converting a Dict of List with Different Size to a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've been struggling to convert a dict to df using `pd.DataFrame(Dict)`, however, I'm getting an error saying `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. Could anybody shed some light on this. Is there any way to go about converting a Dict with different size in 'Value' ?

`Dict= {'Country': [],
 'Organization ': [],
 'Education ': [],
 'City ': ['Toronto']}`

It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide any hints.
Many thanks,
R.

Comment: because you have empty lists for the first 3 columns, what are you trying to do? keep them blank?

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to retain blank ones as is. Well, Is there any way to handle this without having to put [''] manually? I intend to have things automated. My Dict looks like above and am intending to convert it as is. Any way to get around this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need to have either a space or a nan, it cannot be an empty list. since `len(empty_list)= 0` whereas `len(['Toronto'])=1`

Comment: Yes, check answer

Comment: Many thanks for your hint. could you just slightly elaborate on `{k: np.nan if not v else v for k, v in Dict.items()}`, How does one interpret this line of code?

Comment: @Ricardo, it is a dictionary comprehension, you can execute it as a for loop like `for k, v in Dict.items():` , `if not v else v:` , `k: np.nan` so basically a elegant way of writing a for loop.  `dict.items()` helps you iterate over keys and values of a dictionary.

Comment: @anky_91. `df=pd.DataFrame({k: np.nan if not v else v for k, v in Dict.items()})` This line of code doesn't seem to working for a Dict having blank lists for all its columns.           ` Dict = {'A ': [],
 'B ': [],
 'C ': [],
 'D': []}`    The error I'm getting is: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`. Could you assist me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the first 3 columns as blank , you need either a space or `np.nan` not a blank list:

```
Dict= {'Country': [np.nan],
 'Organization ': [np.nan],
 'Education ': [np.nan],
 'City ': ['Toronto']}

print(pd.DataFrame(Dict))
    Country  Organization   Education     City 
0      NaN            NaN         NaN  Toronto
```

**So replace empty lists with `np.nan`:**

```
Dict= {'Country': [],
'Organization ': [],
 'Education ': [],
 'City ': ['Toronto']}

df=pd.DataFrame({k: np.nan if not v else v for k, v in Dict.items()})
print(df)  

   Country  Organization   Education     City 
0      NaN            NaN         NaN  Toronto
```